# Having trouble displaying api data on the page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im making a project where I fetch an image of a recipe card from https://spoonacular.com and I want it displayed on my react.js app. For some reason I can't get the API data from displaying on the page when I run it. Please help Im really stuck. I keep getting the error that recipeList is undefined in Recipe.js but I thought it was defined?

This is my Home.js:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Recipe from "../components/Recipes";

const URL = `https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/716429/information?apiKey=${APIKey}&includeNutrition=false`;

function Home() {
  const [food, setFood] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (food) {
      axios
        .get(URL)
        .then(function (response) {
          const recipeList = response.data;
          setFood(recipeList);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.warn(error);
        });
    }
  }, [food]);

  return (
    <main>
      <Recipe recipeList={food} />
    </main>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

this is my Recipe.js

```
import React from "react";

function Recipe({ recipeList }) {
  return (
    <div className="Recipe">
      <div>{recipeList.title}</div>
      <img src={recipeList.image} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Recipe;
```

Comment: Why do you need `if (food)` in your `useEffect()`? and also `[food]`?

Comment: And also make sure the structure of the response and the way you call each individual data (such as `recipeList.title`) is a match.

Comment: You're fetching data asynchronously, and it's not available on the initial render. Your current return statement expects the data on the initial render, but it has not returned from the server yet (it's undefined).  You must account for this by checking if the data has returned before consuming.  The simplest solution is to move your if(food) check out of your useEffect and place it before your current render. i.e, if(!food) return 'loading…'; return (current return statement)

Answer (score 0):

you need initializing empty

```
const [food, setFood] = useState({});
```

and in useEffect evaluate if food is empty

```
 useEffect(() => {
   const getData=()=>{
      axios
        .get(URL)
        .then(function (response) {
          const {data} = response;
          setFood(data);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.warn(error);
        });
     }
    if(!food){ // validate if food is empthy to get data (food)
        getData()
     }
  }, []); // here is not necesary use food, because never happen anything with that variable
```

Comment: Since the stored value is a json, I don't think it's the right way to initialize the `useState()` with empty string

Answer (score 0):

The response example can be seen [here](https://spoonacular.com/food-api/docs#Get-Recipe-Information).

To call that using axios:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Recipe from "../components/Recipes";

const URL = `https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/716429/information?apiKey=${APIKey}&includeNutrition=false`;

function Home() {
    const [food, setFood] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        // You can add any if-else statement here
        // but you can also do the fetch without it
        axios
            .get(URL)
            .then(function (response) {
                setFood(response.data);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.warn(error);
            });
    }, []);

    return (
        <main>
            <Recipe recipeList={food} />
        </main>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

And based on the response, your `Recipe.js` should working properly.